# Error reversing django migrations with sql_safe_update mode set in MariaDB

Tags: django, mariadb, django-migrations

I am running into issues when I try to reverse migrate one of the migrations in Django due to sql_safe_update mode is set in MariaDB.

The exact sql statement it runs for reverse is:

```
ALTER TABLE `user` DROP COLUMN `pin_code`;
```

And the error that I get from django is:

```
MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1175, 'You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column')
```

Now my database is in inconsistent state because the column has been dropped and failed migration was not rolled back as MySQL DDL statements are not run in transaction. Now even with --fake it shows the same error.

Is there a way to tell django to run migrations with sql_safe_update=0 only for duration of migrations? Note that I cannot turn off sql_safe_update globally as DB admins are adamant on not removing it globally.

Also it is not entirely clear why DROP column requires a WHERE statement?

Answer (score 1):

I further did some debugging and saw that the it does not fail on ALTER TABLE statement, instead it fails on:

```
DELETE FROM `django_migrations` WHERE (`django_migrations`.`app` = 'cards' AND `django_migrations`.`name` = '0023_user_pin_code');
```

This is a problem in django as DELETE statement is run without WHERE clause on a key column. The name is not indexed, which is why the issue crops up.

Let me raise a ticket in Django for the same.